# passing params from child tab-Navigator screen to parent stack-Navigator screen | React native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have this problem with nested navigators:
I want to pass params from a (child navigator) **tab-navigator** screen to a (parent navigator)
**stack-navigator** screen with react navigation *v6*.

my navigation structure looks like this:

```
< STACK NAVIGATOR >:   : parent navigator 
    < some screens here .. />
   *< screen which will receive the params />
  
    < TAB NAVIGATOR >   : child navigator 
         < some screens here .. />
        *< screen which will send params />
    </ TAB NAVIGATOR** > 


</ **STACK NAVIGATOR** >
```

I don't know if there is a built in way to do it with react-navigation, although I did search a bit and found nothing in the docs so if there is any helpful insights, I would be very thankful.

Comment: When you push or navigate to any screen using `navigation.navigate` or `navigation.push` you can send params like `navigation.navigate('ScreenName',{params})` which you can retrieve in ScreenName as `route.params` or `this.props.route.params`

Answer (score 0):

You can make a global state to pass outside of the Child component
and make sure that loading of component to screen is inside
<Stack.Screen>
/* your component and spread the props as stated below  */

</Stact.Screen>

```
const [global,setGlobal]= useState('')


< STACK NAVIGATOR >:   : parent navigator 
      <Stack.Screen>
          {(props) => <Parent global={global} {...props} />}
      </Stack.Screen>
   *< screen which will receive the params />
  
    < TAB NAVIGATOR >   : child navigator 
/// put your component here.....
         <Tab.Screen name='Name'>
               {(props) => <Child setGlobal={setGlobal} {...props} />}
         <\Tab.Screen>

        *< screen which will send params />
    </ TAB NAVIGATOR** > 


</ **STACK NAVIGATOR** >
```

and on your child

```
const Child = ({setGlobal}) => {
    return <Button  onPress={()=> { setGlobal('newValue') }} />
}
export default Child
```